# classe em css usando jinja2 não funciona

Tags: html, css, python, aplicação-web, flask

Estou tentando colocar estilos css, mas só pegou o primeiro bloco de código no meu *style.css* 
*style.css*

```
  h1 {
    color: blue;
}

.login {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 4%;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 12px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #34ADFB;
  transition: background-color 400ms ease-out;
}

.login:hover {
  background-color: #2B96DA;
}

.login:active {
  background-color: #34ADFB;
}
```

*hello.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello from flask</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css')}}">
</head>
<body>
    {%- if name %}
        <h1>Hello {{ name }}!</h1>
    {% else %}
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    {% endif -%}
    <a class="login" href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Fazer login agora!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Quando dou *run* no flask, somente esse bloco aparece:

```
  h1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

obs: já testei meu css no site jsbin, e funcionou normalmente.

Edit:

*estrutura do projeto*

```
flask-test 
   /static 
      style.css 
   /templates 
      hello.html 
      login.html 
   run.py
```

obs2: estou usando o pycharm para fazer o projeto

Comment: Talvez seja somente um detalhe. Tentou mudar de `)}}` para `) }}` (acrescentando um espaço) na linha do css?

Comment: tentei mudar sim, mas continua a mesma coisa. valeu pela ajuda!

Comment: atualize seu post com a estrutura de diretórios do projeto.

Comment: Poderia colocar uma saída do console, e uma do carregamento da página do browser da aba network ?

Comment: tudo o que você está mostrando ai está correto - na minha experiência, esse tipo de "fantasma" acontce quando a gente está salvando as alterações num arquivo, achando que está modificando outro  - no caso: verifique se você realmente está salvando o style.css no lugar certo,  e nao deu um "save as..." e esqueceu em algum ponto.

Comment: Olá, eu abri e reabri pelo pycharm, e está salvando certo(O pycharm tem salvamento automático). Já testei ir no diretório do explorer e abrir o .css em bloco de notas, e está normal. Também tentei executar pelo VS code, mas não acontece nada...

Comment: Consegui resolver, percebi que quando inicio o server pela primeira vez, ele dá o get no meu style.css, e quando eu reinicio ele, ele só dá get no html, e mais nada, mesmo dando F5. achei a solução em no navegador dar CTRL + SHIFT + R, baseado nessa pergunta do stackoverflowi: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45567877/why-wont-my-flask-app-connect-to-my-css-files/45588180

Answer (score -1):

Olá, Você pode fazer um teste utilizando um caminho relativo, ao invés de uma URL dinâmica do css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style.css">
```

Abs.